# Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-keypad

I have a few elements in a RelativeView with the align bottom attribute set, when the soft keyboard comes up the elements are hidden by the soft keyboard.

I would like them to move up so that if there is enough screen space they are shown above the keyboard, or to make the section above the keyboard scrollable so the user can still see the elements.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Updated reference from [android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

Comment: @Dinedal How do u set align bottom attribute to ur RelativeView???

Comment: I posted a simple solution that does not involve adding anything to the manifest. Just a simple layout and android handles the rest. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323758/android-how-to-push-button-above-soft-keyboard/67798240#67798240

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Yes, check out [this article on the Android developers' site](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) which describes how the framework handles the soft keyboard appearing.

The `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute can be used to specify what happens on a per-activity basis: whether the layout is resized or whether it scrolls etc.

Answer (score 112):

You can also use this code in `onCreate()` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: For me even if I set adjustPan screnn move only up to the edit text I've clicked but not the whole layout

Answer (score 42):

Make changes in the activity of your Manifest file like

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**OR**

Make changes in your `onCreate()` method in the activity class like

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Why do you use different flags?

Comment: Current version requires android prefix: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Answer (score 37):

Add in AndroidManifest.xml for your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Comment: According to docs the behaviour is unspecified if you use two "adjust..." flags here. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 25):

similar issue i was facing with my layout which consist scroll view inside.
Whenever i try to select text in EditText,Copy/Cut/Paste action bar gets moved up with below code as such it does not resize layout

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

By modifying it to as below

1. AndroidManifest.xml

   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
2. style.xml file ,in activity style

   true

It worked for me.

Comment: what does it mean actvity style true?

Answer (score 20):

In AndroidManifest.xml, don't forget to set:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and for RelativeLayout inside ScrollView ,set :

```
 android:layout_gravity="center" or android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

it will be okay

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" worked, thanks! :) now EditText moves over the keyboard as I wanted

Answer (score 17):

for Activity in its oncreate methode insert below line

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

and for fragments in its onCreate method

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 12):

There are 3 steps to follow to scroll screen up.

1. Write in manifest file for your activity:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

2. Add following line in oncreate() method of your activity

> getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

3. Then place your whole view in "Scrollview" in XML file like :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:background="@drawable/bg"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>     > 
>     <RelativeLayout
>          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="center" >
>         <TextView />
>          .........
>         <TextView />
>         <EditText >
>             <requestFocus />
>         </EditText>
>         <Button />
>     </RelativeLayout>
>  </ScrollView>
> ```

P.S. Don't forget to add android:layout_gravity="center"  in parent Relative layout.

Answer (score 10):

```
<activity name="ActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```

Add NestedScrollView around layout which you want to scroll, this will perfectly work

Answer (score 6):

I tried a method of Diego Ramírez, it works.
In AndroidManifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
        ...
    </activity>
```

In activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout ...
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Space
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/first_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText ...>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me after looking at a lot of solutions:

In `AndroidManifest.xml` add the following line to an activity declaration in the manifest file of your project.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

The code should look something like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just edited the answer, try with this version (changed "stateVisible" to "stateHidden" and added "adjustPan"). The previous version didn't work for me now either.

Answer (score 5):

I just added the following line to the top level layout and everything worked:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: @yash786 is possibly show button below edittext that receive a focus ? Second question can you share you layout file or answer me how you add edittext a top of keybord ?

Comment: it works for me event without android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Comment: yea this works but also change height of widget and quite ruin view

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution to my problems that it's pretty same as yours.

First of all, I only have a LinearLayout with 2 elements, an ImageView and a LinearLayout wich contains 2 EditText and one Button, so I needed to keep them separate in full screen without keyboard, and when the keyboard appears they should look closer.

So I added the view  between them with the height attribute in 0dp and weight 1, that let me keep  my views separate one form each other. and when the keyboard appers, as they don't have a fix height, they just resize and keep the aspect.

Voila! The layout resize and the distance between my views is the same when the keyboard is or not present.

Comment: Why don't you post the code, for better comprehension?

Comment: I posted a sample code above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31994697/2914140.

Comment: you can achieve this in a less hacky way by using a `ConstraintLayout` and pinning a top section to the top and a bottom section to the bottom. When the keyboard opens it will naturally resize by squeezing the space in the middle (if you use `adjustResize`)

Answer (score 3):

1. If user want this task using manifest then add this line in manifest
2. In manifest add this line: - android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
   e.g.

In Java File or Kotlin File (Programmatically):- If the user wants this using Activity then add the below line in onCreate Method

```
activity?.window()?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is full manifest code

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Scroll View as a Parent and use this Tag in Scroll View

android:fillViewport="true"

Answer (score 1):

if you are in fragments then you  have to add the below code to your onCreate on your activity it solves issue for me

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file add the below line. It will work

```
<activity name="MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: stateVisible was missing in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of methods but at the I added this line in the AndroidManifest.xml file and it worked perfectly

```
<activity
      ...
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is very late however I've discovered that if you add a List View under your edit text then the keyboard will move all layouts under that edittext without moving the ListView

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"



/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"//can make as 1dp
    android:layout_below="@+id/et" // set to below editext
    android:id="@+id/view"
    >
**<any layout**
```

This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single advice solve my issue. **Adjust Pan** is almost as like work **Adjust Resize**. If i set **Adjust Nothing** than layout not move up but it hide my edittext of bottom that i am corrently writing. So after 24 hour of continuous searching I found [this source](https://gist.github.com/grennis/2e3cd5f7a9238c59861015ce0a7c5584) and it solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but I want to add few things.
In Android Studio Version 4.0.1, and Gradle Version 6.1.1, the     `windowSoftInputMode`  will not work as expected if you are adding the following flags in your Activity :

```
getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        );
```

After wasting lot of time, I have found that hack.  In order for `adjustResize` or `AdjustPan`or any attribute of `windowSoftInputMode` to work properly, you need to remove that from your activity.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to make it work while also having the flags active?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the view:

```
view.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted the screen contents to be pushed up with the soft keyboard only in one fragment but not in all the activity fragments.

So I dropped the solution of window params.

My solution is,

1. wrap the contents to be pushed up inside the `Scrollview`.
2. in the fragment `onResume()` add the below code,

   ```
   val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

    // listen for the keyboard popping up and going down..
    requireView().viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        // Check if the ScrollView is scrolled to the bottom
        val isScrolledToBottom =
            binding.scrollView.scrollY >= binding.scrollView.getChildAt(0).height - binding.scrollView.height

        if (imm.isActive && !isScrolledToBottom) {
            binding.scrollView.smoothScrollTo(
                0,
                binding.scrollView.bottom
            )
        }
    }
   ```

This will scroll the contents up when the keyboard is shown very similar to the Activity window_adjust_pan flag.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

**Method 2:**
In your Activity onCreate():

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

OR

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

**Method 3:**
For Fragment onCreate():

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

**Note:** if It's still not working then check your activity and remove this property

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```