# android autocompletetextview hint results hidden under keyboard

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have 3 `autocompletetextview`'s in which i set its adapter to be an `ArrayAdapter<String>` with a very simple `textview` layout.

The `autocompletextview` hint results are showing, but are under the onscreen keyboard(i can see part of it).  how can i make the results show above the `autocompletetextview` rather than below?

```
    airline = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.airline);
    airline.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.autcomplete_dropdown, AIRLINES_AUTOCOMPLETE_ARRAY));

    departLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.departLocation);
    departLocation.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.autcomplete_dropdown, LOCATIONS_AUTOCOMPLETE_ARRAY));

    arriveLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.arriveLocation);
    arriveLocation.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.autcomplete_dropdown, LOCATIONS_AUTOCOMPLETE_ARRAY));
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply limit the drop-down height.

`android:dropDownHeight="200dp"`

Then results don't hide by the soft keyboard.

**Or else do this**

The theory says that `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` should do this but for some reason, it doesn't, so you have to do the same programmatically:

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Answer (score 5):

Use a ScrollView for the layout where your Autocomplete resides and Voila!

Answer (score 3):

Does your Activity adjustResize?

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

reference: [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: yeah, I've got that in the manifest, yet the last few suggestions for the autoComplete dropdown are hidden under the softkeyboard

Answer (score 1):

you should look here : [Creating an input method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)

Composing text before committing

If your IME does text prediction or requires multiple steps to compose a glyph or word, you can show the progress in the text field until the user commits the word, and then you can replace the partial composition with the completed text. You may give special treatment to the text by adding a "span" to it when you pass it to InputConnection#setComposingText().

this way, suggestions will apears on soft keyboard prediction like auto-correction. An other way of doing it will be a fullScreen IME... with ExctractEditText : [See this link...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/ExtractEditText.html)

This is what i usualy have seen in other apps... i don't think the autocompletetextview can be inverted and appears on top of the view, but what's strange is that it usually shows on top of the keyboard not bellow...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this a little while ago. You Can try manipulating the z-index of the elements that are being hidden to force it to the top which would be your views in this case. Hope it works for you !

Comment: Elements that are hidden is the only dropdown list, is there any way to set property to this list?

Answer (score 1):

another quick solution is by using the attribute "android:dropDownAnchor"
to anchor the dropdown to some other view on top of screen

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

Which will auto resize and adjust the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions worked. try this

> android:dropDownHeight="match_parent"

If we didn't mention the dropdown height, it would be considered wrap_content. Therefore the item will show behind the soft keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

Take the autocomplete textviews in respective layouts then you see they opens their values in it only (ABOVE), set autocomplete texview (bottom) of each layouts, as per your question you required three child layouts.

it is really working

Comment: please can you update your answer to fix the broken english? as I'm afraid I have no idea what you are trying to say