# Android: Dropdown of AutoCompleteTextView is covered by the keyboard

Tags: android

I got more or less the same problem as described here:
[android autocompletetextview hint results hidden under keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480529/android-autocompletetextview-hint-results-hidden-under-keyboard)

Can anyone help?

Comment: More or less the same problem? The same problem? Your question is very subjective.

Answer (score 14):

try adding this to your manifest under activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

as per the developer docs i have had pretty good success with that.

Comment: What if we have the `EditText` in the `AlertDialog`?

Comment: thanks, you just saved my day !
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" worked fine for me

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: not working for me :(