# Android: How to push button above soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I've got a "save" button which I want to push up together with the soft keyboard. So when the user clicks an EditText in my layout, then the button has to stay above the keyboard. Now the button becomes hidden underneath the keyboard. How do you do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Comment: @CommonsWare actually, the referenced article is no help here. OP has a button below his EditText field (a common layout). There is actually no way to push up the EditText **and the Button** using the standard input method settings. Unfortunate.

Comment: @DavidWasser: Then make the IME's action button do the same thing as the hidden button.

Comment: @CommonsWare what if there's a checkbox also? Then the IME's action is of no help, actually

Comment: The answers for this question need updating to work with ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You need to set your keyboard's input mode to `adjustResize`. You can do this adding the following line to your activity's attributes in the manifest:

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Here's an example of the attribute added in the activity:

```
<activity 
     android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Comment: It worked! But not completely as expected. See this new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343355/android-scrollview-not-scrolling-with-keyboard-out

Comment: I am using ConstraintLayout, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 51):

Along with Inthathep's answer, you have to add an attribute in the parent viewgroup

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

to work it as desired.
i.e, in manifest file , for the activity add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and 
eg.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" <!-- add this -->
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_assetview_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="Enter comments"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_assetview_postcomment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="POST"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Only this helped.

Comment: dealing with xml has always been a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 27):

Order your layout like this and you will able to put button to above keyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_next"
        android:background="#0ff"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                android:hint="Hint"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Button Next"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In android manifest

```
<application
        ...
        >
        <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
           >
        </activity>
</application>
```

[image]

Note that, instead of `RelativeLayout`, you can also use another `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout` with weight, `CordinatorLayout`, ...

Comment: You should test it with a huge text, say 15 lines. And you'll see that when write it and then click on top line, part of edittext will hide behind the keyboard

Comment: Incase of everything is correct and if you gave windowFullscreen "true" it will not work, so just remove one line from your theme : <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

Comment: @varotariyavajsi thanks brother you saved my time I was messed with this issue thank you very much

Answer (score 11):

So this is a pretty old post, but I struggled with the answers provided. Both oneavi and Intahep are correct, but let me show you EXACTLY where the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` goes.

in Android Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".DataScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".PauseScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".RouteInfo"
               android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> <!--This goes in the specific activity with the button -->
    </activity>
```

Comment: You should test it with a huge text, say 15 lines. And you'll see that when write it and then click on top line, part of edittext will hide behind the keyboard

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to hide the keystroke and, if necessary, press the buttons above the keyboard

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 2):

*Additional point*
Any of the above including `"adjustResize"` will work except if your activity is full screen. That was my case. check your activity code to ensure its not in full screen.

Answer (score 1):

This simple setup scrolls the entire layout up with the keyboard.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_iv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Key points:

- Nothing added to the manifest.
- Image must be "wrap_content" (not fixed size) to allow android to resize it as needed.
- All views must be linked as shown above. The bottom view layout_alignParentBottom="true", the top view layout_alignParentTop="true", and all intermediate views layout_above="@id/view_below".
- The layout_below="@id/view_above" attribute does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

**In AndroidX:**

Use `CoordinatorLayout` for main parent layout and add a `NestedScrollView` for your content and add your layout or button in child of `CoordinatorLayout` to push button above soft keyboard

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"  >
        .......
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/send_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/login" />
```

**photo:**

[image: https://snipboard.io/n45tbx.jpg]