# How to scroll my entire layout when the keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/defaut_padding" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/defaut_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/watermark" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/bitmap_loading"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/photo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="@dimen/smallest_padding" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_picture"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/anonymous_user" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/user"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/defaut_padding"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user"
            android:text="@string/anonymous_user"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/defaut_padding"
    android:background="@drawable/textfield"
    android:hint="@string/description_hint"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/publish"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/confirm_button_selector"
    android:text="@string/confirm_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/big_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I want to scroll it when the soft keyboard appears when I start to digit at the EditText. How can I do this? Currenty the scroll works, but the keyboard appears above the button, and I want the button above the keyboard

I've tried to move the scrool when the user clicks in the EditText, doing something like this:

```
mSv.scrollTo(0, mSv.getBottom());
```

where mSv is my ScrollView

But it only works when the user clicks in the EditText at the second time.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try this customview as a parent group element in your layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on

Comment: Thank you. I've use this custom layout, and put the mSv.scrollTo(0, mSv.getBottom()); when the keyboard is show, but the layout it is not moved yet

Comment: See a very simple solution that works at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323758/android-how-to-push-button-above-soft-keyboard/67798240#67798240

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your Keyboard to pan instead of resize. You could do that in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file, for your particular `Activity`, add the below to it

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**or**

**If you want to hide then:**

```
EditText editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**If want to show:**

```
EditText editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
editTextSearch.requestFocus();
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `RelativeLayout` (outside of `ScrollView`) being aligned to the bottom, it will stick to the bottom of the available screen—above the keyboard. `ScrollView` then needs a bottom margin to not overlay the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

    <ScrollView      
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"    
        android:orientation="vertical"      
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" >    

        /* Here your elements ... like EditText */

    </ScrollView>   

    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" > 

        <Button      
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:layout_height="48dp"
         android:text="ddd" />        

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works only if you (as far as I could evaluate)

- have a `RelativeLayout` as parent
- have a `ScrollView` as the only child besides the `RelativeLayout` containing the button OR have another View (e.g. `LinearLayout`) containing a `ScrollView` somewhere (for whatever reason)

If you don't want the button to always stick to the bottom, you need to detect if the keyboard is shown or not as explained in Pragnani's link.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not works. My keyboard still appears above the button.

Comment: Sorry. I discovered that things are little bit more complicated. Try my updated answer. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you again, I've already tried this, but what happens is that the button will appears over the entire layout, and what I want to do is make the entire layout (button and other views scroll)

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You want to scroll the whole layout, this works, but the bottom part still is behind the keyboard? Then simply put your stuff into the parent `RelativeLayout` and add the `alignParentBottom` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47048436/1972597). It should solve the problem *"..that the button will appears over the entire layout, and what I want to do is make the entire layout (button and other views scroll)"*