# Scrolling scrollview programmatically when keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been searching for a long time, but none of the answers were helpful.

I'm making a chat app. When the user clicks on input edit text the keyboard shows up, and I want to automatically scroll to the bottom of scroll view, but it does not work as expected. It looks like it thinks that the scrollview has different dimensions than it really has. (probably doesn't realize that keyboard is taking some space)

When keyboard is hidden, programitacally scrolling to the bottom works as expected.

This is what i have now:

In manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ChatActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

In activity:

```
        messageEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                if (!hasFocus)
                {
                    HideKeyboard(v);
                   // ScrollToBottom ();
                }
                else
                {
                    ScrollToBottom();
                    messagesScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            messageEditText.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }); 

                    ScrollToBottom();
                }
            }
        });

  private void ScrollToBottom ()
    {
        messagesLinearLayout.requestLayout();
        messagesLinearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messagesScrollView.scrollTo(0, messagesScrollView.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LetsGOFriends.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            android:background="#242A2F"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.LetsGOFriends.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trainerNameChat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profilePictureImageView"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profilePictureImageView"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="LoriMontana"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trainerCodeChat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profilePictureImageView"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainerNameChat"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="0467 0321 3849"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePictureImageView"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageViewRounded"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_default_profile_picture"
                    app:strokeColor="#484848"
                    app:strokeWidth="1dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/languageFlagChatImageView"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainerNameChat"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trainerNameChat"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trainerNameChat"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/messagesScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/messagesLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:focusable="true" />
    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

                app:boxBackgroundColor="#242A2F"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="15dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="15dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="15dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="15dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_700"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                app:endIconContentDescription="Send"
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                app:endIconMode="custom"
                app:endIconTint="@color/white"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Enter your message.."
                    android:maxLength="250"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="#D3D3D3" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think it's something wrong with layout file.

Comment: try this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owNy_PJ5iY4 here they're using this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37277176/12811664

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for scrolling down:

```
messagesScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```