# Button OnClickListener is not working when soft keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, buttonclick

When the activity is launched, the user is prompted to enter in his email. A `TextView` and `Button` are visible along with keyboard. However, when the user taps on the button, it does not work - rather the keyboard disapears, then the user has to tap on the button again for it to work. Therefore, it takes two user taps to get this button to work. How can we get the button listener working while the keyboard is visible?

Here is what I have tried, in the `manifest` I put this code:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/provisioning_background_color">


<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323758/android-how-to-push-button-above-soft-keyboard -->

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_next_email">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/sign_in_logo_height"
            android:src = "@drawable/bg_form_top"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sign_in_logo_top_margin"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_already_have_account"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textColor="@color/app_text_color"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:text="@string/already_have_account"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/app_text_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="@color/app_text_color"
            android:hint="Enter Email"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_next_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/create_account_buttons"
    android:textSize="@dimen/create_account_buttons_txt_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="NEXT"
    style="@style/provisioning_buttons"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/text_email"/>
```

Comment: And what is the issue with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` ? Case by case, you can use `adjustPan` too