# How to lift buttons above the keyboard

Tags: android

I have an EditText field, and 2 buttons at the bottom: Next and Back.
now when I click on the edit text, the buttons are hidden under the keyboard.
I saw this post on Stack: [Android: How to push button above soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323758/android-how-to-push-button-above-soft-keyboard). using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the app manifest file for that specific activity.

But, I saw other apps code where the buttons are pushed up, and they do not use this attribute at the manifest file. So it is probably done in the xml file.

So, how can it be done via XML? Also, if I simply use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest, am I supposed to encounter problems? How does it lift exactly these 2 buttons? What would happen if I had more content in the activity? How would it lift it above the keyboard?

Comment: i never used `android:windowSoftInputMode` and still my layout scroll upside by default..it seems, Android OS do this by default in most cases..thats why you don't see this in other code

Comment: It isn't done in XML perhaps via relative layout weight or something?

Comment: I posted a simple solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323758/android-how-to-push-button-above-soft-keyboard/67798240#67798240