# How can I move button with keyboard when keyboard is opened

Tags: android, android-keypad

How can I move button like below image : [image]tton when keyboard is show display.

Comment: Unclear question. Kindly state your problem clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside your Manifest file, in your activity, add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` . Example:

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
....>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

just Add in your AndroidManifest.xml for your particular activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown/19406877#19406877