# Move toolbar up when keyboard shown

Tags: android, github, toolbar, evernote

In my app i have created a toolbar which sticks at the bottom of the screen now I want to move the toolbar above keyboard whenever the keyboard is show. I have tried the following ways but it didn't work

Tried this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

and this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

This is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:id="@+id/evmainText"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
    />
    <include layout="@layout/text_toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's the toolbar file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textFormatToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_back_text"
/>
```

I want to displsy toolbar like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past with a button bar but through the `AndroidManifest`. Try adding to the manifest, in the activity that contains the toolbar, the following:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <!-- Something else -->
</activity>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I you read my question again you will know that I have already tried it

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that you might be missing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the root of your RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its helf ful to you:

To enable adjustResize add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in your activity's parent layout

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742154/4116924), I was able to make this happens by:

1/ Add this attribute to the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

2/ Add this attribute to your toolbar

```
android:windowActionBarOverlay="true"
```