# Does anyone know what is this called?

Tags: android

At first UI is as follow
[image: Image 1]

After clicking on edit TextView it comes over the keyboard
[image: Image 2]

How can i achieve the same UI? Is there any library?

Comment: That is just view inside of a RelativeLayout and is allignedParentBottom="true"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown
In short look for: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.ChatActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_chat">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial) is a GitHub repo with a tutorial on how to implement it. If you visit the XML code, you will see that similar code is done as what is offered in the comments and previous answer.