# Android RecyclerView - Keep last visible item visible when keyboard opened

Tags: android, keyboard, android-recyclerview

If you're using Telegram, you may have seen, if you keep last visible item on X, when keyboard opens, you still see item X and if you close the keyboard, the item X is still on its position.

**example:**

> when keyboard is closed already:
>
> Item 1
>
> Item 2
>
> when keyboard is opened:
>
> item 1
>
> item 2
>
> keyboard
>
> when you close the keyboard, the first step is what you will see.

I want to implement something like that. How can I do this?

Comment: try out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown

Comment: what is item x exactly

Comment: what you want exactly code to detect keyboard open or close??

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez just using AdjustReize and/or AdjustPan wont help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

`setStackFromEnd()` property solved this question.