# Layout not move up or panned when soft keyboard is shown in android java

Tags: java, android

I want to resize or pan layout when keyboard is displayed.
Here's my source code.

**activity_forget_password.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/forgot_password_bg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:largeHeap="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">

        <com.opkix.app.utils.OpenSassTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/forget_password_introduce_string"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".activities.auth.ForgetPasswordActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:noHistory="true">
```

As you can see from my source code I added fitsSystemWindows and windowSoftInputMode.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown?rq=1

Comment: Hi, I already checked that question

Comment: Try to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"

Comment: sorry but that also doesn't work

Comment: Can you add screensshot of screen.

Comment: here's a link to screenshot, as you see the bottom textview is hidden when keyboard is shown. http://prntscr.com/dzpbvq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133894/discussion-between-frank-lindstrom-and-mdg5435).

Answer (score 0):

add ScrollView as parent of RelativeLayout.It is not proper answer but it will work.

example

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
 <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/forgot_password_bg"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:largeHeap="true"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp">

            <com.opkix.app.utils.OpenSassTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/forget_password_introduce_string"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then there is some other issue because for me it worked.

Comment: In my code format was RelativeLayout ScrollView RelativeLayout ,i added extra relativeLayout before ScrollView

Comment: In genymotion, when i tap edittext and after that, when i press enter the layout moves, do you have any idea for this problem?

Comment: In emulator and genymotion it happens but not on real device

Comment: no enter key because of EditText attribute(i dont know which).