# layout gravity center does not move up when softkeyboard is visible

Tags: android

My code is as shown below:

activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    >

    <!--<ScrollView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:fillViewport="true">-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/m"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="SellTm"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/partener"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/m"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Partner"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usernameLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/partener"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="@string/text_user_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorConifer"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userNameInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/usernameLabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorConifer"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passwordLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userNameInput"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/text_password"
                android:textColor="@color/colorConifer"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/passwordLabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorConifer"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <!--<Button-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/okButton"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="200dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="50dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_below="@+id/passwordInput"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="40dp"-->
                <!--android:background="@color/colorConifer"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/text_ok"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@android:color/white"-->
                <!--android:textSize="18sp" />-->

        </RelativeLayout>
    <!--</ScrollView>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` , I have written`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` against activty, still the layout is not moving up when keyboard is opened. Is there anything missing in the layout?

Comment: Did you try adjustpan in windowSoftInputMode in manifest

Comment: @AbhayBohra I have tried it. but it is not working

Comment: HI Mrugesh did you solve with my reply? if yes please accept the response. hope in any case is solved

Answer (score 1):

Where did you write windowSoftInputMode in the Manifest?

try

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

into the tag `<activity>` and before `<intent-filter>`
be sure that the instruction is inside the activity you are considering when you want that the soft keyboard raises

EDIT Alternatively you can try to add in onCreate

> setWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

and also try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown) in the Manifest

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not giving me any solution

Comment: if you get rid of ScrollView it works? try before on a less complex layout, with just a text view and add incrementally to see if works.

Comment: I have tried using simple layout. it is moving up . Now, I want to move the layout up till the end , how to do that? (I have updated the code in my question for that)

Comment: really good Mrugesh, keep adding things, my guess is that with scrollView you could have problems, see also my EDIT above