# How to make in app custom keyboard behave like a system keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-softkeyboard, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an in app keyboard that tries to behave like a system keyboard. So far it pops up from the bottom using Bottom Sheet, which is great.

However, unlike a system keyboard, it does not push the entire layout up when you select an EditText that might otherwise get hidden. So far all the solutions I saw on StackOverFlow seem to be about **Soft/System Keyboard** not an **in-app** implementation like mine.

**Here is my activity with 3 Edit Texts**

[image]

**This is what happens if I click on the *last* Edit Text. It gets covered by the keyboard in blue**
[image]

**This is how I want it to be. Everything getting pushed up.**

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you clarify what is the layout you're using?

Comment: I'm using CoordinatorLayout since BottomSheet requires a CoordinatorLayout. Maybe I shouldn't use BottomSheet? I am just using BottomSheet because of its clean sliding animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim That's for Soft Keyboard (system), not in App Keyboard.

Comment: using bottomsheet as a custom keyboard seems not the right approach. you cannot touch the items on background when you swipe the bottomsheet up.

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim I think you are confusing BottomSheetDialog with BottomSheet. I can definitely touch anything in the background when the BottomSheet is expanded.

Comment: what you can do is you can listen the sheet states (expanded, collapsed, dragging, etc.) using callback and adjust your views on the background accordingly.

Comment: How do I adjust my views? I'm thinking of putting them inside a ScrollView?