# How to move all elements in Constraint Layout Up on focus in Edit text Field?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, onfocus

I am trying to make a layout with an Edit Text field for email requests. The design makes it so that the keyboard is always opened over the editText View which makes it impossible to know what you are entering. I have tried many suggestions on stack overflow but most of them are for API <24 (though I don't think this has much effect on this).

In the Activity file I have tried the following:

```
window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)

window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)

window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)


window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

In Android Manifest I have also tried the following, both in conjunction and separately:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I also wrapped my layout in a ScrollView as described by  Heena 
 here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39867438/5635144

Below is my XML and the accompanying activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EmailResetActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="419dp"
        android:background="@drawable/signin_up_anim"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ...
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/e_request"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email_address"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintgrey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bg" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonsContainer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/e_request">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendRequestBtn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/large_btn"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

class EmailResetActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit private var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_reset)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()



        val animDrawable = resetPassInfoBg.background as AnimationDrawable
        animDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2500)
        animDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(1500)
        animDrawable.start()


        sendRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val email = e_request.getText().toString().trim()

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(application, "Enter your email ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@OnClickListener
            }


        })


    }

}
```

I would like for the layout to be moved up so the editText Field is visible but currently nothing is making it work.

Comment: how about remove the `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: <activity    android:name=".EditextActivity"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

Comment: I just tried your layout on an API 19 and on an API 26 (Android 8.0). It's working for both devices. No need to change anything in manifest. (???). Can you share your Activity?

Comment: I have added it for your attention. I don't know why it simply won't work on my device.

Comment: ok, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

With `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` the application is not able to calculate how to scroll your view, because your layout has no limits.