# How can I push the screen up when the keyboard is opened so the user would see the auto complete?

Tags: android, kotlin, autocomplete, keyboard

I have a field with auto complete the becomes visible once the user starts typing. My problem is that while the keyboard doesn't hide the input field itself, it hides the recycler view under it with the auto complete and users don't can't see that it even appeared.

Just to be clear, I already have - `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` in my menifest, that is not the issue, it is the view that's under the inout that's being hidden.

** Getting suggestions for question to which their answers is what I've mentinon is NOT my issue. PLease don't suggest the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: An image of what happens now and how you would like it would help.

Answer (score 0):

if your keyboard open upon `recyclerview` you can try this

once put your layout under `ScrollView` as `rootView`

after that add this code in your `activity`

```
int[] location = new int[2];
recyclerView.getLocationInWindow(location);
scrollview.scrollTo(location[0],location[1] + 100);
```