# How to use a ScrollView without keyboard altering view?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have limited space in one of my views and I am trying to implement a Scroll View which can help to resolve the limited space issue. However when I try to implement the scroll view it messes-up the keyboard, every time I now try to edit a EditText it causes the elements within the view to move up with the keyboard.

Is there any other solutions or work arounds which I can try to implement?

I have tried the solution at [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown) which suggest to add the following code to the Manifest  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize` which prevents the keyboard from jumping up at runtime.

I have also tried to set the gravity of the scrollview and use different layouts example: linear, constraint, relative-layouts. I have tried to make a custom keyboard class and to implement it by setting it in the relevant view activity class (Not my code but tried to implement it)

```
Here is the solution for this fix
- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in Manifest File
- Make a class "CommentKeyBoardFix.Java" and copy and paste the below code.

public class CommentKeyBoardFix
{
private View mChildOfContent;
private int usableHeightPrevious;
private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;
private Rect contentAreaOfWindowBounds = new Rect();

public CommentKeyBoardFix(Activity activity)
{
    FrameLayout content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
    mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this::possiblyResizeChildOfContent);
    frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
}

private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent()
{
    int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
    if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious)
    {
        int heightDifference = 0;
        if (heightDifference > (usableHeightNow /4))
        {
            // keyboard probably just became visible
            frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightNow - heightDifference;
        }
        else
        {
            // keyboard probably just became hidden
            frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightNow;
        }
        mChildOfContent.layout(contentAreaOfWindowBounds.left, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.top, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.right, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.bottom);
        mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
        usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
    }
}

private int computeUsableHeight()
{
    mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(contentAreaOfWindowBounds);
    return contentAreaOfWindowBounds.height();
}
}

And then call this class in your Activity or Fragment
setContentView(R.layout.your_comments_layout)
CommentKeyBoardFix(this) ---> For Kotlin
or
new CommentKeyBoardFix(this) ---> For Java
```

This gives a static member error which I don't know how to solve.

However none of these solved the problem.

My current layout file which is causing the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/freq_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Freq"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/freq"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:digits="0123456789.,"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_r1_unit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:tooltipText="unit"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/duty_cycle_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/duty_cycle"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/duty_cycle_percentage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="50%"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="50" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/main_layout1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Design"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_design"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"
            />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            >

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>



</merge>
```

If I remove the scroll view it solves the problem however, I need to add a scroll view since this .xml file is used as a snippet in a different .xml file where the space is very limited.

Is there any other possible work-around of the implementation of a scroll view? Is there any good explanation to why this scroll view is causing this bug and considering the space issue what other alternatives are there that I can take into account, which can deliver similar results to that of a scroll view, without causing the keyboard error?

Comment: Try this at once

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Comment: Hi  Rahul Kushwaha, thanks for the comment. It unfortunately does't solve the problem.

Comment: have you tried using programming?

Comment: I have tried a few code samples found on the web, but it didn't fix it. Any suggestions?