# I want scroll RecyclerView item above to keyboard when keyboard open

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have edittext inside recyclerview item and I want scroll recyclerview item above to keyboard when user click on edittext which is inside the recyclerview row. I saw same in Instagram feed list but I am not able achieve like Instagram. Check Instagram screenshot what I am going to achieve.

```
[enter image description here][1]KeyboardUtils.registerSoftInputChangedListener(getActivity(), new KeyboardUtils.OnSoftInputChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSoftInputChanged(int height) {
         enter image description here
            recyclerViewPostList.smoothScrollBy(0, height);
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes I am trying to scroll by  x and y accordingly keyboard height but did not get the well output. 


**KeyboardUtils.registerSoftInputChangedListener(getActivity(), new KeyboardUtils.OnSoftInputChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSoftInputChanged(int height) {
             
                recyclerViewPostList.smoothScrollBy(0, height);
            }
        });**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Answer (score 0):

add this line into your manifiest as below into your activity tag.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

or you can also add it from your **activity** by puttion below code `oncreate` of your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

and for **Fragment**

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```