# Android - How would I push my edittexts above my softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml, android-softkeyboard

I have tried various solutions. I have tried adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my manifest along with `adjustPan`. I am not sure why I am having such a hard time with this problem since it seems like such an easy fix and I have come across multiple posts asking a similar question but none of the solutions work for me.

Below is my XML layout file

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/truckForm_txv_appTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Truck Owner Form"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/truckForm_LL_firstAndLast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/truckForm_ed_first"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
                android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:nextFocusForward="@id/signUp_ed_last"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/truckForm_ed_last"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
                android:hint="@string/hint_last_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/truckForm_ed_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/truckForm_ed_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
            android:hint="Truck Title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/truckForm_ed_phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
            android:hint="Truck Owner's Phone Number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/truckForm_spin_genres"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/truckForm_ed_genre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/truckForm_btn_signUp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</ScrollView>
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

**FOUND A SOLUTION THAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM:**

Soon after I posted this I came across this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914507/12257857 which helped me find the solution to my problem.

My solution was adding:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN); in my onCreate() of the activity with the XML. Thank you guys!
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot and describe what you want instead.

Comment: in manifest Have you put android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" inside the activity tag that contains this xml?

Comment: I have tried putting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the activity tag in the manifest

Comment: I actually just found the solution and edited my original post with the solution! Thanks for the help though.