# Software keyboard overlaps content of jetpack compose view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

Suppose I have some activity with a jetpack-compose content

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ScrollableColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .border(4.dp, Color.Red)
            ) {
                val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

                TextField(
                    value = text,
                    onValueChange = setText,
                    label = {},
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )

                for (i in 0..100) {
                    Text("Item #$i")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If I were to launch this activity and focus on the TextField a software keyboard would pop up.

The interface, however, would not react to it. ScrollableColumn's bottom border (`.border(4.dp, Color.Red)`) would not be visible, as well as 100th item (`Text("Item #$i")`).

In other words, software keyboard overlaps content.

How can I make jetpack compose respect visible area changes (due to software keyboard)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the standard android procedure, but I don't know if a Compose specific way exists.

If you set the SoftInputMode to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`, the Layout will resize on keyboard change.

```kotlin
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        
        setContent { /* Composable Content */ }
    }
}
```

otherwise, you could use the flags in the manifest. See here for more information:
[Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: It did the trick, `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` (that which you hinted at) works as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Setting the flag in the manifest is the same as setting it in code just your preference I guess.

Comment: I think this only set bottom inset when keyboard popup, but the content could still not fully visible after keyboard popup, unless `ScrollableColumn` would keep the focus item scrolling to visible position.

Comment: thanks but on keyboard ime next button click, the text field still not visible, ie the scrollable column not scrolled, any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: @Hoby I think you have to scroll manually, you can calculate the position by measuring everything in the Column and then set the scroll state to the relative position of the focused element.

Comment: @2jan222 first thanks a lot for your response, yeah this is what I did to solve this using 'scrollState.smoothScrollTo(i * viewSize)' but I was asking if there is any cleaner way

Comment: @2jan222 do you have a code snippet to know how to perform this calculation ?

Comment: @OscarIvan If you have a fixed height for the items you have to get the index of it multiply the height and then pass it to the remembered state for the list. I am not sure if you need to calculate in pixels or dp. If it is the first case you have to include a calculation including the current density. From the top of my head it's: Let``val d = LocalDensity.current`` then use ``val px = with(d) { dpValue.toPx() }``

Comment: @OscarIvan https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/ScrollState#animateScrollTo(kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec)

Comment: Adding: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to your Activity element inside Android Manifest file works the best!

Comment: SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE is deprecated, any updates on that?

Comment: I, personally, use the flag (should not be deprecated) in the manifest or Accompanist's inset library (answer below)

Comment: Hello 
In my case, I have to handle both the scenario in my project:

Example:
Case 1: Need to resize the screen (AdjustResize)
Case 2: No need to resize the screen  (AdjustResize) 

If we give this in the manifest and activity how can I handle these two scenarios in my project:

Note: Assume that both are different composes and screens.

Comment: Deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74036164/4897831

Comment: it's not going to work for all layouts, your input field may appear behind keyboard...

Answer (score 52):

Besides Compose, no external libraries are needed for this now.
Set `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` on the activity in your manifest file

e.g.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then for the composable that you want the UI to react to, you can use [`Modifier.imePadding()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).imePadding()) which reacts to IME visibility

```kotlin
Box(Modifier.imePadding()) {
  // content
}
```

Comment: Hello 
In my case, I have to handle both the scenario in my project:

Example:
Case 1: Need to resize the screen (AdjustResize)
Case 2: No need to resize the screen  (AdjustResize) 

If we give this in the manifest and activity how can I handle these two scenarios in my project:

Note: Assume that both are different composes and screens.

Comment: I don't think "true" is a possible value for this field (which is misspelled)

Comment: this is the correct answer , no need any more to 3rd library ... tested right now,  imePadding do the job very well

Comment: it means that you may forget about adding `.imePadding()` for each screens where keyboard can be shown... because with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` the system doesn't put the content above the keyboard automatically

Comment: also what to do you if some screens may not have scrolling attribute (the content is adaptive)? but we set adjustResize for the whole activity, which means it effects all screens...

Comment: the problem that for some screens I need to have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` behaviour but for some not because it make hide your input field behind keyboard for some designs... I need `adjustResize` + `.imePadding()` only for screens like chat list (scrollable) with input field below the screen but for all others keep the default behaviour

Comment: I think it will not scroll the content to make text field visible automatically

Comment: Thanks, i used Just imePadding and didnt worked, and blatantly spend time on finding keyboard height by globalpositioning, view invalidation etc to be added as padding, but just this 1 manifest flag does this for you. Helpful!

Answer (score 23):

You can use Accompanist's inset library https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets

first use *ProvideWindowInsets* at the root of your composable hierarchy most of the time below your app theme compose and set *windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled* true

```
ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {
// content  }
```

The use *navigationBarsWithImePadding()* modifier on TextField

```
OutlinedTextField(
// other params,
modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsWithImePadding() )
```

Finaly make sure to call *WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)* from your activity(inside *onCreate*). If you want Software keyboard on/off to animate set your activity's *windowSoftInputMode* *adjustResize* in AndroidManifests

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: I only used `ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true)` in a Jetpack compose `TextField` as explained in the answer and it worked for me.

Comment: works very good for me, the first answer was not enough for me since I had something below the text field which I wanted to move above keyboard too.

Comment: it's not for sroll layouts

Comment: What if in 1 compose screen I want to adjust resize and in another not?

Comment: Deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74036164/4897831

Answer (score 6):

Use the modifier `imePadding()`. This will allow the specific compositions to adjust themselves when the keyboard pops up. This does not require you to set any flag on the activity

Comment: `imePadding()` also requires `.fillMaxHeight()`

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem.

Use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` which will observe the actual IME rect size and will be triggered when the soft keyboard is fully visible.

Worked solution for me:

```
val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val view = LocalView.current
DisposableEffect(view) {
    val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        scope.launch { bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView() }
    }
    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
    onDispose { view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener) }
}
TextField(
    modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester),
    ...
)
```

[Origin here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120?hl=sr#:%7E:text=7p%2Dgroup.com%3E-,%2371,-Mar%207%2C%202022)

Answer (score 2):

I came up with idea of using accompanist insets library.

Someone could be interested because my approach **does not modificate** the contents of an application.

I link my post below:

[(Compose UI) - Keyboard (IME) overlaps content of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597345/compose-ui-keyboard-ime-overlaps-content-of-app/70597435#70597435)

Answer (score 2):

In my case just adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`  to activity was enough to solve the problem.
It depends on how you build your UI. If yours screen's root is a vertically scrollable container or a Box, the keyboard resize might get managed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your TextField scroll up when keyboard appears.
The following it work for me.
You need to add these

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    
    setContent { /* Composable Content */ }
}
```

And add this to your app/build.gradle

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets-ui:0.24.7-alpha"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my edge-to-edge application I just use `Spacer(8.dp + Modifier.height(WindowInsets.safeDrawing.asPaddingValues().calculateBottomPadding()))` at the bottom of the screen. It adds padding for the navbar, or keyboard if it is open, to ensure that the bottom elements do not overlap.

It should also works in non-edge-to-edge apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Is deprecated now in compose use below way for make screen resizable on keyboard Open.

First, add below code in your manifest (add in all activities if have more activities)

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
/>
```

Now, in your views of screens where you want to resize add below:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.imePadding()) {

}
```

Instead of column you can use Box, Row etc.