# How to unhide a TextField hidden by keyboard in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I have a main activity with 3 TextFields that are offset from the top because I am using tabbed navigation :

[image]

But what happens on small screens is that the keyboard hides the third textfield "Receiver".

How can I solve this ? Would using a ScrollableLayout be a solution (so the user could scroll to *unhide* the third textfield) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Accompanist Insets library](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/insets) in three steps :-

1- in your activity call setDecorFitsSystemWindows

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

2- call the ProvideWindowInsets function and wrap your content

```
ProvideWindowInsets {
  // your content
}
```

3- call navigationBarsWithImePadding modifier in your content

**Full Example :-**

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)  // step 1
setContent {
    MaterialTheme {
        ProvideWindowInsets { // step 2
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .navigationBarsWithImePadding() // step 3
            ) {
                // your content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Add this to your manifest

[https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility[Documentation][1]](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility%5BDocumentation%5D%5B1%5D)

android:windowsSoftInputMode defines the positioning of the elements.

Comment: Well adding this does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in the onCreate before setContent

`window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`

Credits:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64053897/15880865

.

Comment: Does not work (at least on API 30) most apparently because it was depreciated in API 26

Answer (score 0):

So I managed do this using the [accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/insets) and setting the modifier to `Modifier.navigationBarsWithImePadding()`