# EditText keyboard scroll margin

Tags: android

[image]

There is a character counter under the pink line, which I would like to see while typing, but it's covered by the keyboard. Everything is inside a scroll view, and the text field scrolls up when focused, but I want to make it "overscroll" - how can we adjust the scroll offset, or whatever it's called?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/length_limit"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
      android:maxLength="250"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

or if you want to change margins check this
[KeyBoard changing](https://gist.github.com/GolnazTorabi/0c5a04652a91e37307d645fe1e803f82)
And for implementing that :
[onResume](https://gist.github.com/GolnazTorabi/2fa7ff73fde9ac67c2da0a3910393592)